# Convert for to for loop to do while loop

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop, do-while

I'm trying to convert this **for loop** to a **do while loop** and keep it a `7 x 7` matrix

*For loop to print the number `7 x 7`*:

```
for (int height = 0; height < 7; height++){
    cout << numberMatrix[height][digitOne] << " ";
    cout << numberMatrix[height][digitTwo] << " ";
    cout << numberMatrix[height][digitThree] << " ";
    cout << endl;
}
```

Right output:

[image]

Here is my code after converting but it doesn't come out right.

*For loop to print the number `7 x 7`*:

```
 int height = 0;
    while (height < 7) {
        cout << numberMatrix[height][digitOne] << " ";
        cout << numberMatrix[height][digitTwo] << " ";
        cout << numberMatrix[height][digitThree] << " ";
        height++;
    }
}
```

Wrong output:

[image]

Comment: `cout <<endl;` you forget this line in while loop

Comment: Please, don't post picture, copy/past textual output

Comment: the two code snippets are equivalent (except for the missing `cout<<endl` in  the while)

Comment: That's a while loop. A do while loop has the condition at the end, and must always be executed at least once. So it can't easily replace a for if the empty or null case is allowed.

Answer (score 0):

In this case you should use while/for loop.
While loop should be used only when you need at least once loop should be evaluated even if condition is false.

Still you can try this `do-while` :

```
int height = -1;
do{
    if(height > 0){
        cout << numberMatrix[height][digitOne] << " ";
        cout << numberMatrix[height][digitTwo] << " ";
        cout << numberMatrix[height][digitThree] << " ";
        cout << endl;
    }
    height++;
}while( height < 7);
```

Comment: Why `int height = -1;`? It will print nothing in the first iteration and you are adding an extra useless `if`.